Update order of relation items in Typeorm
is there a way to update order of related items in Typeorm?
For example:
First I'm saving item:
const item = new Item();
item.name = 'item';
item.relations = [related1,related2,related3];

this.dataSource.manager.save(item);

Later I want to update item:
const item = await this.dataSource.getRepository(Item)
            .findOne({
                where: { id: id  }
            });
item.name = 'updatedItem';
item.relations = [related3,related2,related1];

this.dataSource.manager.save(item);

Unfortunatelly, all changes are saved but relation order is still the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Not specific to TypeORM, but something important to understand about databases and relations in general; the order in which you save the data has no inherent meaning to the database. It doesn't keep track of the order you associate a relationship, only that such a relationship exists. If the order is important to you, then you'll need to add something like an order column to whatever the related relation is, which you can update and store the correct order alongside the associated data.
